# renaming a file with Dockerfile instructions

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker which clones a public repository, builds a library and the built library is then used by the main application. My local machine is on MacOS, the docker is a Linux distro, so I just can't compile and move the file. The library needs to be renamed (mandatory, the output is .dylib, but to use it in python it must become .so) and moved (optional).

ADD and COPY take my local machine as reference for the source, the relevant part of the Dockerfile is:

```
RUN git clone https://gitlab.com/somelib/somelib.git
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"
RUN cargo build --release --manifest-path=somelib/Cargo.toml
RUN cp somelib/target/release/libsomelib.dylib app/main/util/somelib.so #<-- ERROR HERE
```

But this doesn't work because it fails to find libsomelib.dylib

```
cp: cannot stat 'somelib/target/release/libsomelib.dylib': No such file or directory
```

Is this possible or is docker not meant for this this operation?

Comment: you can cp or mv a file as RUN instruction. The error indicates that your assumption about the output from cargo build doesnt hold up. You could comment the last line out, build it like that and then run the container interactivly to inspect the file system.

Comment: I'd normally expect a Linux shared library to be named `*.so`; does the Rust build system generate an appropriate platform-specific name, so you don't need to rename the file?  (After the `cargo build` step, inside the image, is there a `libsomelib.so` file and not a MacOS-style `*.dylib` file?)

Comment: thanks to both, yep after the inspection the linux library is indeed .so already, that was it..!